# To insert Yii::t() into the php line

Tags: php

I would like to insert Yii::t() into the following line:

```
<?= isset($quantity_types[$model->min_quantity]) ? $quantity_types[$model->min_quantity] : $quantity_types[1] ?>
```

Actually my aim is to change the label of the second option in the line, as you see from the line, it displays the result of the selected one out of two options.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Update you question and add the rest part of code .. the translation should be done in the echo part  and  not in model attribute

Comment: didn't get you, can you please elaborate it..? or share some screen shots..

Comment: I have the code line which is shown above and I would like somehow to insert Yii::t() into the line. There is no any other code that is related to the line above.